# Why are imported TypeScript enums undefined but work when assigned to a variable

Tags: typescript, webpack

There are many questions relating to this behaviour but the answers just give a couple of work-arounds without explaining *why* it doesn't work - or why the workaround does the trick, for that matter.

When I export and import an enum, the enum itself is `undefined` but when I assign it to a variable, it will work. This seems completely bonkers and unintuitive to me.

The enum is exported as

```js
export enum SkillType {
  action = 'action',
  language = 'language',
  knowledge = 'knowledge',
}
```

In my Vue component I have the following function:

```js
import { SkillType } from '@/model';

isLanguageSkill(skill: CharacterSkill) {
  return skill.type === SkillType.language;
}
```

This does not work, because - as I found through the debugger - `SkillType` is `undefined`. But when I change the code to

```js
import { SkillType } from '@/model';

skillType = SkillType;

isLanguageSkill(skill: CharacterSkill) {
  return skill.type === this.skillType.language;
}
```

Everything works as expected. What is going on here?!

Update: I'm using Webpack with a configuration generated by the Vue CLI. As there is a lot of stuff in there, I'm not posting it in full, you can find it at https://github.com/milgner/sr6-character-sheet in case you're interested.

Comment: How do you export your enum?

Comment: I don't think it relates to typescript, but to the bundler

Comment: Good point about the bundler! I'll do some additional searching in that direction.